# Custom DialogPreference with custom layout: IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, android-custom-view, dialog-preference

I have a custom DialogPreference with a custom dialog layout. The UI crashes on the second time I click on it, with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

I tried inflate with `attachToRoot` equals to `false`. But then the dialog displayed with empty body.

I am guessing I should call this `removeView()` when the dialog is dismissed. But I didn't find where should I add that piece of code.

**Custom layout:**

```
public class PeriodPicker extends LinearLayout {

    public PeriodPicker(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflate(context, R.layout.period_picker, this);    
    }
```

**Custom DialogPreference:**

```
public class PeriodPreference extends DialogPreference {
    public PeriodPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        periodPicker = new PeriodPicker(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        return periodPicker;
    }
```